# python combined advantages of pd.DataFrame and np.array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I process multiple **pandas dataframes** in my project (approx. 8 columns / 500 rows / numerical data only). It takes a lot of time just to iterate over the data frames (do some calculation stuff with pointclouds …).
So, I think about shifting my project from the pd.dataframe approach to the **np.array** approach. Because numpy has a much better performance ([link](https://www.javatpoint.com/pandas-vs-numpy)).
But, in my opinion, the python source code becomes more confusing: I.e. select a column:

- pandas `dataframe_pointcloud[‘magnitude’]`

vs

- numpy `array_pointcloud[:,4]`

Is there a good solution that combines the advantages of np.array (faster workflow with numerical data) and pd.dataframe (readability of source code)?

Comment: Without code I have no idea how to speed-up your calculations, but I doubt switching everything to numpy will improve it much (AFAIK pandas already uses a numpy array as the underlying data representation, but I could be wrong).

Comment: You might find you get more helpful answers if you share code for a specific operation you're performing on your dataframes, and ask how to get a performance boost. You will probably find the advice you get can be carried over to some of your other operations as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can first access a dataframe column by its name and then convert it to numpy array using the `.to_numpy()` method:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
        data=np.random.rand(500, 8),
        columns=list('abcdefgh'))

%timeit df['a'] + df['b']
94.3 µs ± 1.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit df['a'].to_numpy() + df['b'].to_numpy()
10.1 µs ± 230 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

This simple trick with such small dataframe already yield almost a 10x improvement.

As other people commented, it is hard to help any further without any code or what you have already tried. More tips for enhacing pandas performances can be found in the doc page [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html).